# How to extract the last value of a group in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-analysis

I have a huge data that needs to be grouped based on its 'IDs' and only the last value of each ID needs to be exported into a SINGLE csv/excel file.

```
incl = ['A', 'B', 'C']
for k, g in df[df['ID'].isin(incl)].groupby('ID'):
    g.tail(1).to_csv(f'{k}.csv')
```

I have tried this but it makes different csv files for each ID instead of a one big file containing the last value of each group.

Sample data:

```
       ID        Date   Open   High    Low
30  UNITY  2020-06-18  11.50  11.75  11.41
31  UNITY  2020-06-21  11.44  11.50  10.88
32  UNITY  2020-06-22  11.26  11.78  11.26
33  UNITY  2020-06-23  11.72  12.08  11.53
34  UNITY  2020-06-24  11.51  11.59  11.40
35  UNITY  2020-06-25  11.85  11.85  11.11
36   SSOM  2020-05-03  27.50  27.95  27.00
37   SSOM  2020-05-05  27.50  27.50  27.50
38   SSOM  2020-05-06  29.20  29.56  29.20
39   SSOM  2020-05-07  31.77  31.77  31.77
```

Comment: Sorry, i still don't get it. can u elaborate?

Comment: _"each ID needs to be exported into a SINGLE csv/excel file."_ you want to write to a single file, then just groupby and call last then write that variable to a csv, whats so hard to understand?

Comment: No, i want last values from the 300+ IDs I hv into one csv file. Each ID currently has more than 100 values.

Comment: can you add some sample data

Comment: I hv included sample data into the question. The last row of every ID the latest data therefore I need the 'last rows' of all the IDs into one file where I can analyze them.

Comment: `df.groupby('ID').last().to_csv('file.csv')`

Comment: do you want the last row or the max date?

Comment: Just the last row